# Query Logic SQL

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, logic

I have a table that contains this data.

```
main_id main_name other_name
   1      aa aa     bb bb 
   1      aa aa     cc cc
   2      bb bb     aa aa
   2      bb bb     cc cc
   3      cc cc     aa aa
   3      cc cc     bb bb
```

I have a field where user will search by name, when user searches for name the query should get  data like main_name and other_name.

What I have tried so far is:

```
select where main_name like $data_entered or other_name like $data_entered
```

the result of this gives me

```
main_id main_name other_name
   1      aa aa     cc cc
   3      cc cc     aa aa
   3      cc cc     bb bb
```

I need to include:

```
main_id main_name other_name
   1      aa aa     bb bb
```

id did a query like this:

```
select where main_name like $data_entered or (main_name like $data_entered or 
other_name like $data_entered)
```

but still can't get:

```
main_id main_name other_name
   1      aa aa     bb bb
```

Any help would be appreciated

By the way, I'm coding php, with codeigniter framework.

Comment: you have said that you want o/p like above that include Main name as "aa aa" but for which Dataentered you need o/p like this

Comment: @HardikParmar every main_name has associated other_name, other_name could be more than 1. now when user search, result should include data_entered "like" main_name and main_name with all its other_name if there's other_name "like" data_entered"

Comment: If poosible provide creation of table & insert query for the above code

Comment: What is the value of $data_entered? Why do you need this specific row? `1      aa aa     bb bb`